# JTabbedPanel change selected tab background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, border, jtabbedpane

I'm attempting to change the color of the border of a JTabbedPane based on the selected tab. Using answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124474/jtabbedpane-set-default-border-around-tabs) and [on the web](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2139618), I've managed this:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;

public class TabbedPaneTest implements Runnable {
    JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();;

    public void run() {
        // magenta border first so any changes will be obvious
        setTabbedPaneBorderColor(new Color(255, 0, 255));

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        pane.addTab("A", createTab(Color.RED));
        pane.addTab("B", createTab(Color.YELLOW));
        pane.addTab("C", createTab(Color.BLUE));
        pane.addChangeListener(new TabSelected());
        container.add(pane);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(container);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTab(Color color) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, 2));
        return p;
    }

    private class TabSelected implements ChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int index = pane.getSelectedIndex();

            switch (index) {
            case 0:
                setTabbedPaneBorderColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 1:
                setTabbedPaneBorderColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
            case 2:
                setTabbedPaneBorderColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public void setTabbedPaneBorderColor(Color tabBorderColor) {

        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.shadow", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.light", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.highlight", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", tabBorderColor);
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", tabBorderColor);


        pane.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI() {
               @Override
               protected void installDefaults() {
                   super.installDefaults();
                   highlight = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.light");
                   lightHighlight = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.highlight");
                   shadow = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.shadow");
                   darkShadow =UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.darkShadow");
                   focus = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.focus");
               }
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TabbedPaneTest());
    }
}
```

In particular, the setTabbedPaneBorderColor() method does exactly what I wanted (that is, it modifies the fancy border around the tabs, rather than the border on the panels contained in it or a plain rectangular border around the entire space the JTabbedPane occupies). For some reason this example throws an error that doesn't show up in my actual program (I think it's related to the SwingWorker and EDT). Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the selected tab's background.

The relevant property is

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected",Color.MAGENTA);
```

However, I don't seem to have a way to use that in the tabUI (it's baffling, but there's no background Color variable in BasicTabbedPaneUI).

Edit: Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will come by with a good answer, but if you googled this my current solution is to use a neutral color for the selected tab's background color since there seems to be no simple way to update it. I also switched to a neutral tab border (even though you CAN update that as the example shows) and created the colored borders inside the contained JPanels. It's not ideal, but it looks pretty good and I don't have time to continue looking for a cleaner solution at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is worked for me

```
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+Pressed].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.GRAY));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
            UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Selected].backgroundPainter", new BackgroundPainter(Color.white));
```

## BackgroundPainter class

```
public class BackgroundPainter implements Painter<JComponent> {

  private Color color = null;

  BackgroundPainter(Color c) {
    color = c;
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {
    if (color != null) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for me, it worked, I just set the UImanager's TabbedPane.selected color  property before creation of JTabbedPane object.

```
 UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.red);

      tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
```

Refer this link, i'm sure it will work for you too.

http://esus.com/changing-the-color-of-the-selected-tab-of-a-jtabbedpane/